# C# convert int to string with padding zeros?

Tags: c#, formatting, number-formatting

In C# I have an integer value which need to be convereted to string but it needs to add zeros before:

For Example:

```
int i = 1;
```

When I convert it to string it needs to  become 0001

I need to know the syntax in C#.

Comment: This may help you - [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx). Good luck

Answer (score 911, accepted):

`i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')` - okay, but doesn't work for negative numbers
`i.ToString("0000");` - explicit form
`i.ToString("D4");` - short form format specifier
`$"{i:0000}";` - string interpolation (C# 6.0+)

Comment: @Rahul Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#FFormatString

Answer (score 302):

```
i.ToString("D4");
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString) on format specifiers.

Comment: this way worked for me String.Format("{0:D4}", number);

Answer (score 127):

Here's a good example:

```
int number = 1;
//D4 = pad with 0000
string outputValue = String.Format("{0:D4}", number);
Console.WriteLine(outputValue);//Prints 0001
//OR
outputValue = number.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
Console.WriteLine(outputValue);//Prints 0001 as well
```

Comment: Just a hint: You don't need to ToString() the string. PadLeft already returns a string.

Answer (score 72):

C# 6.0 style string interpolation

```
int i = 1;
var str1 = $"{i:D4}";
var str2 = $"{i:0000}";
```

Comment: This one looks very nice. Good way to avoid `$"some text {x.ToStrig("D4")} after text"`

Answer (score 69):

You can use:

```
int x = 1;
x.ToString("0000");
```

Comment: And a second way to use the same format string: `string.Format("{0:0000}", x)`

Answer (score 18):

```
i.ToString("0000");
```

Answer (score 6):

Easy peasy

```
int i = 1;
i.ToString("0###")
```

Comment: It'd be better if you add an explanation for '#'.

Answer (score 5):

Simply

```
int i=123;
string paddedI = i.ToString("D4");
```

Answer (score 4):

.NET has an easy function to do that in the `String` class.
Just use:

```
.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')  // that will fill your number with 0 on the left, up to 4 length

int i = 1; 
i.toString().PadLeft(4,'0')  // will return "0001"
```

Comment: int i = 1002; 
string str = i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'); // returns "1002" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int p = 3; // fixed length padding
int n = 55; // number to test

string t = n.ToString("D" + p); // magic     

Console.WriteLine("Hello, world! >> {0}", t);

// outputs: 
// Hello, world! >> 055
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ToLeadZeros(this int strNum, int num)
{
    var str = strNum.ToString();
    return str.PadLeft(str.Length + num, '0');
}

// var i = 1;
// string num = i.ToLeadZeros(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the given answers are slow or very slow or don't work for negative numbers.

Try this one:

```
}
    //
    //
    ///<summary>Format a value with a fixed number of digits.</summary>
    public static string Pad( this long v, int digits ) {
        int negative = 0;
        if ( v < 0 ) {
            negative = 1;
            v = Math.Abs( v );
        }
        var source = v.ToString();
        var length = source.Length;
        int max = length;
        if ( max < digits ) {
            max = digits;
        }
        max += negative;
        var ca = new char[ max ];
        for ( int i = 0; i < max; i++ ) {
            ca[ i ] = '0';
        }
        while ( length > 0 ) {
            ca[ --max ] = source[ --length ];
        }
        if ( 0 != negative ) ca[ 0 ] = '-';
        return new string( ca );
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here I want to pad my number with 4 digit.  For instance, if it is 1 then 
it should show as 0001, if it 11 it should show as 0011.

Below is the code that accomplishes this:

```
reciptno=1; // Pass only integer.

string formatted = string.Format("{0:0000}", reciptno);

TxtRecNo.Text = formatted; // Output=0001
```

I implemented this code to generate money receipt number for a PDF file.

Answer (score -2):

```
string hello = "Hello C# Corner.";

string helloHash = hello.PadLeft(5, '#');  

Console.WriteLine(helloHash);
```

Output :-

```
#####Hello C# Corner.
```

Answer (score -5):

To pad `int i` to match the string length of `int x`, when both can be negative:

```
i.ToString().PadLeft((int)Math.Log10(Math.Abs(x < 0 ? x * 10 : x)) + 1, '0')
```

Comment: Unnecessarily confusing especially when there is a very simple solution.