# How can I format a number into a string with leading zeros?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I have a number that I need to convert to a string. First I used this:

```
Key = i.ToString();
```

But I realize it's being sorted in a strange order and so I need to pad it with zeros. How could I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# convert int to string with padding zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros)

Answer (score 456, accepted):

Rather simple:

```
Key = i.ToString("D2");
```

`D` stands for "decimal number", `2` for the number of digits to print.

Comment: if you use `string.Format("D2", value)` you'll get `D2` in the output. this doesn't work. We must use `"{0:00}"` in this case.

Comment: You should use `string.Format("{0:D2}", value)` instead.  Just saying `string.Format("D2", ...)` won't replace anything no matter what since you don't have a placeholder.

Comment: @infinitypanda realize that this will only work when `value` is an int. If `value` is a double, for instance, it will have to be `string.Format("{0:00}", value)`

Comment: if we are talking about 'leading digits' I think the answer would be i.ToString("00"); where "00" represents the leading zeros.. you can increase this amount as much as possible.

Comment: This will fail with `System.FormatException` if the number is a **decimal**. Better to use `.ToString("N0").PadLeft(2, '0')`. However, `PadLeft` does not work properly with negative numbers (zeros in front of negative sumbol).

Answer (score 285):

See [String formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) for some example uses of String.Format

Actually a better example of [formatting int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier)

```
String.Format("{0:00000}", 15);          // "00015"
```

or use [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
$"{15:00000}";                           // "00015"
```

Comment: Note that String.Format("{0:00000}", "15"); returns "15", i.e. it does not work on a string.

Comment: Even shorter way: `$"{15:D5}";` will result in an output of: `"00015"`.

Comment: If you have `int i` and want 8 digits, simply use `var iStr = $"{i:D8}`.

Answer (score 91):

If you like to keep it fixed width, for example 10 digits, do it like this

```
Key = i.ToString("0000000000");
```

Replace with as many digits as you like.

`i = 123` will then result in `Key = "0000000123"`.

Answer (score 80):

Since nobody has yet mentioned this, if you are using C# version 6 or above (i.e. Visual Studio 2015) then you can use [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx) to simplify your code. So instead of using `string.Format(...)`, you can just do this:

```
Key = $"{i:D2}";
```

Answer (score 39):

use:

```
i.ToString("D10")
```

See [Int32.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (MSDN), and [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) (MSDN).

Or use `String.PadLeft`. For example,

```
int i = 321;
Key = i.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Would result in `0000000321`.  Though `String.PadLeft` would not work for negative numbers.

See [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) (MSDN).

Comment: I'd guess that will screw you once you try to use it with negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks - I used the second one.  I left out the ".ToString()" - it still works.

Answer (score 27):

For interpolated strings:

```
$"Int value: {someInt:D4} or {someInt:0000}. Float: {someFloat: 00.00}"
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36536254/1663001) I posted 3 years before you.

Comment: @DavidG I suspect there was some sort of housekeeping with questions and responses getting merged. Paul posted basically the same answer five years before you.

Comment: Paul edited their question in 2019 to include the updated info. I added my answer in 2016.

Comment: @DavidG I feel like it's kindof nuts that I've got someone on StackOverflow on the other side of the world accusing me of some committing sort of stolen valor over posting a bit of syntax that's built into a language.

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
Key = i.ToString("000000");
```

Personally, though, I'd see if you can't sort on the integer directly, rather than the string representation.

Answer (score 15):

Usually String.Format("format", object) is preferable to object.ToString("format"). Therefore,

```
String.Format("{0:00000}", 15);
```

is preferable to,

```
Key = i.ToString("000000");
```

Comment: Yes, as @cja asked, why is it preferable? And I'm not arguing against the assertion, I'd like to know why.

Comment: First syntax "feels" more precise, predictable, and clear.  And it would be better stated as Key = String.Format("{0:00000}", 15);  that is being compared to Key = i.ToString("000000");   With the first syntax, I'm pretty sure I know exactly the result I'll get, and if bychance I'm one character off, I know exactly what to change (format string.  So, in short, to me it's preferable for emotional personal preference, weakly supported by one almost-plausible half-reason ;-)  So it's decided then?

Answer (score 5):

```
int num=1;
string number=num.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')
```

Output="00001"

EDIT: Changed to match the PadLeft amount

Answer (score 3):

Here I want my no to limit in 4 digit like if it is 1 it should show as 0001,if it 11 it should show as 0011..Below are the code.

```
        reciptno=1;//Pass only integer.

        string formatted = string.Format("{0:0000}", reciptno);

        TxtRecNo.Text = formatted;//Output=0001..
```

I implemented this code to generate Money receipt no.

Answer (score 3):

I found a better way tried all the way but not worked for me

```
Convert.ToDecimal(LN).ToString("000000#");
```

LN is Int64