# How to Prefix '0' (zero) to integer value

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I need to prefix a zero to an integer.
Initially I have string which has 12 chars, first 7 are alphabets and 5 are numeric values.
The generated string some times have a zero at starting position of numeric values. for example ABCDEF**0**1234, and my scenario is to generate a range of strings from the generated string. Suppose I want to generate a range (assume 3 in number), so it would be ABCDEF01235, ABCDEF01236, ABCDEF01237.

When I try to convert a string which has a 0 (as shown above) to int, it returns only 1234.
Is there any way to do this, without truncating zero?

Comment: `1234 == 01234` for integers, `0` will be ignored. For displaying purpose you can use string format to pad a leading `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate [How can I format a number into a string with leading zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418324/c-sharp-how-can-i-format-a-number-into-a-string-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) to expand a given string to a given total length:

```
int num = 1234;
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'));  // "01234"
```

Comment: We can do that using PadLeft, my question is can we convert to int when a string has prefixed with zero. It seems to be not possible by looking at the comments below.

Comment: @sham leading zeros make no sense for an integer -- can't you generate your range of numbers, then pad after converting back to a string?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I guess that would be the only option left out.

Answer (score 6):

```
 int num = 1234;
 Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("D5"));  // "01234"
```

Answer (score 0):

No with `int`.

You have to use `string` to concatenate the parsed number and the `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 1234;
Console.WriteLine($"{num:d5}");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use string.Format

```
    int num = 1234;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("0{0}", num));
```