# How to create a “0000001” type number format in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How do I create a “0000001”-type number format in C#?

```
    0000001
    0000002
    0000003
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    0000010
    0000011
    .
    .
    .
    0000100
    0000101
```

How could I generate this type of number format in C#/.NET?

Comment: Generate it WHERE? Ever heard of string.Format - look up the format strings, there is one for formatting numbers that does put leading zeroes as needed.

Comment: Either change `0000003` example or add clarification, as you are confusing fellow stackoverflowers with what you want. ( I think you want binary  padded to 8 digits )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format a number into a string with leading zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418324/how-can-i-format-a-number-into-a-string-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0000000}", number);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Convert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and pass it to the **base** parameter. Like `2, 8, 16`, if that's what you mean.

```
int number = 124;
string binary = Convert.ToString(number, 2); // Output: 1111100
```

Answer (score 2):

Numbers/values don't have a format unless you decide to get a string representation of the value itself.

To get string representation of `int` value you can use `ToString` with format specified:

```
var value = 0;
var valueStringRepresentation = value.ToString("0000000");
```

`"0"` in `ToString()` call is a *zero placeholder* and means:

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.
>
> from [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 1;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("D8"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use PadLeft in C#, like below:

```
string s = "1"；
Console.WriteLine(s.PadLeft(7, '0'));
```

Please visit *[String.PadLeft Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx)* (MSDN) for details.