# Generate random int using random byte generator

Tags: c#

I m using random generator what takes the length of random bytes as an input and returns byte array. What i need now is to convert that byte array to 8 digit integer and from that to a string.

```
byte[] randomData = this.GetRandomArray(4);
SecretCode = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(randomData, 0)).ToString().Substring(0, 7);
```

But some occasions the int is shorter than 8 digits and my method fails. How can i make sure that the byte array generated can be converted to 8 digi int number?

Comment: I'd set some constraints on MSB bytes, for example a minimum value so generated integer will be big enough (8 digits or more). As alternative you may generate a new number when what you have doesn't satisfy that criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option:

```
myString = BitConverter.ToUInt32(randomData, 0).toString("D8");
```

Note - [using `ToUInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32(v=vs.110).aspx) is a more sensible approach than converting to signed integer and taking the absolute value (it also doubles the number of values you can generate since `-123` and `123` will result in a different string output, which they won't if you use `Math.Abs`.); and the format `"D8"` should convert to eight digits including leading zeros.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5418425/1967396

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `<stringCode>.PadLeft(8, "0")`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your method is failing on the `Substring`? As far as I can see there's a number of issues:

1. It'll fail if you don't get 4 bytes back (ArgumentException on `BitConverter.ToInt32`)
2. It'll fail if the string isn't long enough (your problem from above)
3. It'll truncate at seven chars, not eight, as you want.

You can use the `PadLeft` function to pad with zeros. If want eight then code should look like:

```
var s = Math.Abs(
           BitConverter.ToInt32(randomData, 0))
               .ToString()
               .PadLeft(8, '0')
               .Substring(0, 8);
```

For seven, replace the `8` with a `7`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate eight zeros before trying to take the Substring(), then take the last 8 characters.

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("00000000").append(Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(randomData, 0)).ToString());
SecretCode = s.substring(s.length()-7);
```

Your other option is to use a formatter to ensure the stringification of the bits returns leading zeros.