# Calculate hex offset

Tags: c#, string, hex

Currently I am working on a simple binary viewer(hex viewer), which opens binary files and output the code as hex values. I also want to make an offset which shows the position of the first hex value in each line. The offset should be of course also in hex format. Now I have the problem that I don't know how to add zeros to the offset and how many I need to add. It should like that:

[image]

You can see that the offset has some zeros at the beginning. I want to calculate how many zeros I need to add and how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format a number into a string with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418324/how-can-i-format-a-number-into-a-string-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding '0's you mean padding right?

You can achieve that by using `string.Pad`

```
uint offset = 0x0000000F;
string offsetPadded = offset.ToString("X").PadLeft(8,'0'); // The 'X' formats to hex
```

The resulting string should be `"0000000F"`

The ammount of zeroes is usually either 8 or 16 (32-64 bits). If you want to support files larger than 4GB, you should use 16 zeros (64bits)

Comment: Oh thanks. But how can I calculate how many zeros I need to add? I have the amount of bytes but idk how to calculate the amount of zeros.

Comment: The ammount of zeroes is usually either 8 or 16 (32-64 bits). If you want to support files larger than 4GB, you should use 16 zeros (64bits)