# How to assign 01 which should not get converted to 1 with Int32 in C# and gives 01 when refered

Tags: c#, integer, int32

-How to assign 01 which should not get converted to 1 with Int32 in C# and gives 01 when referred.

Comment: You can't store leading zero's in a numeric type.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: leading zeros are dropped in numbers, you can force the format to show leading zeros, but 1 and 01 are stored exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. "01" is a string representation of some sort, not an actual value of an integer with value "1". Data types in .NET usually don't have formatting.

Using `ToString` you can [format an integer to the format you require](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5418324/993547). If that is not what you want, you should use `string`.

Answer (score 0):

In such case you don't need an integer but string instead:

```
string x = "01"
```

Unless what you need is a binary number:

```
in x = 0b01
```

Another option would be to store the value in an integer variable and format it with left-padded zero just before you need it:

```
int x = 1;
string formatted = x.ToString("D2");
```