# DateTime in militaryformat

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am trying to get a time variable that always uses 4 digits to represent the time as per below.

I have tried the following

```
 string slotStartTimeInMilitaryFormat = $"{timeSlotsStartTime.Hour}{timeSlotsStartTime.Minute}";
```

Problem is that I need 1AM to be 0100 and 9PM to be 2100 in other words always a 4 digit representation of the time

but my code makes it 100 instead of 0100 etc.

How can I ensure I always get the 4 digit representation

0000
0030
0100

1300
1330
1400

Comment: Does [String.PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0) work for you?

Comment: timeSlotsStartTime.ToString("HHmm");

Comment: @JohnG's answer is correct as `timeSlotsStartTime.ToString("HHmm")` will format the hour as 24-hour based and fulfill the 4 digits as the requirement mentioned.

Comment: @JohnG worked like a charm, if you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
string slotStartTimeInMilitaryFormat = timeSlotsStartTime.ToString("HHmm");
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the answers at [How can I format a number into a string with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418324/how-can-i-format-a-number-into-a-string-with-leading-zeros/36536254)

Use String Interpolation:

`$"{15:00000}";                           // "00015"`