# Generating a number with 7 digits with the ability to have zeros at the front

Tags: c#, winforms, random, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# convert int to string with padding zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros)

I am trying to generate a random number however in the ranges I have included "0000000, 9999999" I want it to show these zeros when a number is generated for example the following outputs would be:

"00037544"
"01659369" 
"75484957"
"00000001"

I am using the:

```
    int num = rnd.Next(0000000, 9999999);
```

The problem with that is sometimes it will generate:

"1648"
"947596"
"18500" etc

Is there something that im missing?

Thanks for looking

Comment: [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to convert it to the string and then use `PadLeft`.

```
string number = num.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');
```

Or Simply

```
string number = num.ToString("0000000");
```

Answer (score 8):

`int` just represents a number; it doesn't know how many zeroes it has.

When you *display* that number, you can give it as many leading zeroes as you want.

[For example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), `num.ToString("D7")` will create a string with enough leading zeroes to make it 7 digits long, as will `String.Format("{0:D7}", num)`. `Console.WriteLine("{0:D7}", num)` works the same way.

Comment: I think the commas `,` in the last example should be colons `:`. See the syntax in the Remarks section of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx).

Comment: @Jeppe yup, looks like you're right. Merry Christmas :p

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

You're generating integers, and you need to format them. something like `num.ToString("0000000")`should suffice.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this is C#. Editing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Any number with zeros to the left are logically identical to the same number without these zeros. I think what you want is a way to print the zeros on screen.

Example: 5 is equal to 00005; but you want to print the number 5 with 5 digits.
The way you would do this is language dependent.

Comment: This stills answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
          Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(0000000, 9999999);
        string num2 = num.ToString("D7");
```

Comment: This doesn't work will still come back with 5 instead of 7 digits. Doesn't display the whole number with zeros before. Thanks for trying.

Comment: :D..but it works fine here..:(