# Counter with 5 digits

Tags: c#, filenames, counter, auto-increment

I want counter with 5 digits, for exaple: 00000, 00001, 00002....
I creating files with this command:

```
FileStream Fl = File.Create(@"C:\\U\\L\\Desktop\\" + "i" + (counter) + ".xml");
```

Definition of counter:

```
int counter;
```

My increment:
`counter++`;

Have you any idea, how i could make 5 digits counter? Thanks for all ideas:)

Comment: `counter.ToString("00000");`

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
  counter.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')
```

Comment: In general you should not use `PadLeft()` because it doesn't work with negative numbers. It's fine for the OP's requirement and it seems very unlikely you'd ever need to pad negative numbers with leading zeroes, but worth pointing this out methinks.

Answer (score 15):

About [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
int value = 123;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00000"));
// Displays 00123
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a standard formatting string:

```
... + counter.ToString("D5") + ...
```

Or with `Format` method:

```
string.Format("... {0:D5} ...", counter)
```

---

With the *[string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)* of C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015) and later, that will be:

```
$"... {counter:D5} ..."
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the appropriate format specification when converting the counter to a string.

Try this:

```
string counterString = counter.ToString("00000");
```

Or (equivalent):

```
string counterString = counter.ToString("d5");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PadLeft` with `String.Format`. Note that you should use `Path.Combine` if you build paths.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    string counterText = (counter++).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
    string fileName = string.Format("i{0}.xml", counterText);
    string fullName = Path.Combine(@"C:\U\L\Desktop\", fileName);
    FileStream Fl = File.Create(fullName);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Although I agree that using `Path.Combine` is the way to go, this doesn't actually answer the question...

Comment: I think you need `{0:D5}` though.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen + Nolonar: Thanks. Edited my answer to use `PadLeft` instead.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: There are several ways to do it. I prefer `PadLeft` if i can since it's more explicit.

Comment: Although `string.PadLeft()` works for this particular example, it fails spectacularly for negative numbers. Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
int counter = 5;
string asString = counter.ToString("D5");
```

or

```
asString = string.Format("{0:00000}", counter);
```

output will be `00005`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToString function:

```
counter.ToString("00000");
```