# C# For Loop not iterating correctly

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a 4 byte value that I convert to an Int32 and then display it in a textbox.  No problems there.  The problem comes in when I try padding the string with 0's.  When I display the decimal number it should always contain 8 characters, so if its less than that I want to pad it with 0's.

```
string parmDecString = BitConverter.ToInt32(testNum, 0).ToString();
Console.WriteLine("length: {0} - {1}", parmDecString.Length, (8 - parmDecString.Length));
for (int l=0; l < (8-parmDecString.Length); l++)
{
    parmDecString = "0" + parmDecString;
}
textBox74.Text = parmDecString;
```

Here's the output in the textbox I get based on different 'parmDecString' values:

```
parmDecString = "123"
Console:  length: 3 - 5
textbox:  000123   <=== only 3 times in the 'for' loop, expected 5x

parmDecString = "12345"
Console:  length: 5 - 3
textbox:  0012345   <=== only 2 times in the 'for' loop, expected 3x

parmDecString = "12345678"
Console:  length: 8 - 0
textbox:  12345678   <=== as expected
```

Comment: `parmDecString.Length` is changing.

Comment: I agree with SLaks

Comment: Or, just use PadLeft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros).

Comment: parmDecString = parmDecString.PadLeft(8,'0');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parmDecString.Length increases at every loop, try to assign it to a variable before beginning the iteration

Answer (score 6):

First off, the *right* answer to this is just use the [provided format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case, if you stored the number as `paramDec` you would use `paramDec.ToString("D8");` for an 8-digit integer string representation.

The reason your `for` loop isn't working is that you are iterating until you reach `8 - paramDecString.Length` but that length *keeps changing* as you append 0s. It would work if you stored the value off first:

```
int numZeroes = (8-parmDecString.Length); 
for (int l=0; l < numZeroes; l++)
{
    parmDecString = "0" + parmDecString;
}
```

Also, string appending like that is expensive. Consider using `StringBuilder` instead as it doesn't create a new string every time you append to it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to C#, so I had no idea I could even use the 8-digit integer string representation.  I changed the code to use that and its working exactly as expected.  This is greatly appreciated... I'll store this away so I don't make the same stupid mistake next time.

Answer (score 2):

So you screwed up your loop by changing the bounds of the loop from within the loop... but really the loop wasn't necessary in the first place:

```
"123".PadLeft(8,'0') //ftw
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (int l=0; l < (8-parmDecString.Length); l++)
```

with:

```
int limit = 8-parmDecString.Length;
for (int l=0; l < (OriginalLength); l++)
```

That way changing length of string will not affect your loop.