# Convert string[] to Int[] without losing leading zeros

Tags: c#

**Input:**

```
string param = "1100,1110,0110,0001";
```

**Output:**

```
int[] matrix = new[]
    {
              1,1,0,0,
              1,1,1,0,
              0,1,1,0,
              0,0,0,1
    };
```

**What I did?**

First of all I splited string to string[].

```
string[] resultantArray = param.Split(',');
```

Created one method, where I passed my string[].

```
var intArray = toIntArray(resultantArray);

static private int[] toIntArray(string[] strArray)
{        
    int[] intArray = new int[strArray.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
    {
        intArray[i] = int.Parse(strArray[i]);
    }

    return intArray;
}
```

**Issue?**

I tried many solutions of SO, but none of them helped me.

Ended up with array without leading zeroes.

Comment: You want a 1d array with 4x4=16 elements, right?

Comment: yes, that's it. but with leading zeros.

Comment: but in your code you construct a 1d array with only **four** elements.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# convert int to string with padding zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros)

Comment: I'm a little confused here. How can you tell if an `int` has leading zeros or not? Wouldn't the value `1` always have leading zeros? can you make an `int` with value `1` that doesn't have leading zeros? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: You're splitting on the comma, which gives you four strings with "1"s and "0"s. For your function to work as it is, you want an array with sixteen strings of "1"s or "0"s: `resultantArray = string.Join("", param.Split(',')).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- determine all digits: `.Where(char.IsDigit)`
- convert the selected `char`-digits into `integer`: `.Select(x => x-'0')` (this is not as pretty as `int.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` but it's super fast)

Code:

```
string param = "1100,1110,0110,0001";
int[] result = param.Where(char.IsDigit).Select(x => x-'0').ToArray();
```

As CodesInChaos commented, this could lead to an error if there are [other](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx) type of Digits within your input like e.g. Thai digit characters: '๐' '๑' '๒' '๓' '๔' '๕' '๖' '๗' '๘' '๙'  where `char.IsDigit == true` - if you need to handle such special cases you can allow only `0` and `1` in your result `.Where("01".Contains)`

Answer (score 5):

You could also remove the commas and convert the result character-wise as follows using Linq.

```
string param = "1100,1110,0110,0001";
int[] result = param.Replace(",", "").Select(c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Converting the character to int will return the character's ascii value

Comment: Char.GetNumericValue returns a double though, so either change the result to double[] or add the (int) cast

Answer (score 3):

yet another way to do this

```
static private IEnumerable<int> toIntArray(string[] strArray)
{
    foreach (string str in strArray)
    {
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            yield return (int)char.GetNumericValue(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
        string input = "1100,1110,0110,0001";

        var result = input
            .Split(',')
            .Select(e => e.ToCharArray()
                .Select(f => int.Parse(f.ToString())).ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] s=param.split(',');
Char[] c;
foreach(string i in s){
 c+=i.ToCharArray()
}
int[] myintarray;
int j=0;
foreach(char i in c){
myintarray[j]=(int)i;
j++
}
```