# How to convert an integer to its string representation adding padding zeros

Tags: c#

```
int num = 00;
string s=num.ToString();
```

It is giving value "0". The expected result is "00". How to do this?

Can anyone Help me?

Comment: `string s=num.ToString("D2");`

Comment: Are you expecting `int num = 00;` and `int num = 0;` to do different things? If you are, you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# convert int to string with padding zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in your value assignment.   An `int` of 00 always has value 0.  If you want to always show two digits, you need to apply a format to your `ToString()` call

```
int num = 00;
string s= num.ToString("D2");
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result using the implementation of the ToString() method passing a parameter "D2" as shown in the demo link: http://rextester.com/JKIDK14711 
Or you can get more information about the parameters that ToString() accepts from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx