# how to add zeros for integer variable

Tags: c#, int

I'm very new to c# programming. I want to know how to add leading zeros for a integer type in c#.

ex:

int value = 23;

I want to use it like this ;

0023

Thanks in advance

Comment: A `Integer` has no leading zeros. `0023 == 23`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# convert int to string with padding zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros)

Comment: @TomTom: There's no need to be rude. Do you consider 1.0 and 1.00 to be the same as well? Because in C# decimals, they have different representations... Those are trailing rather than leading zeroes, of course, but the difference between `double` and `decimal` could easily be surprising.

Comment: @TomTom: And yet in C# they're different (using the decimal type). That's my point. Things you learn in school may act differently in computing. In school, I'd learn that integers are infinite, and that adding 1 to an integer always made it larger. That's not true for `int` though, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want to add padding zeros.

string format specifier has a very simple method to this.

```
string valueAfterpadding;
int value = 23;
valueAfterpadding = value.ToString("D4");
Console.WriteLine(valueAfterpadding );
```

this solve your problem. just google it.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. There's no such contextual information in an `int`. An integer is just an integer.

If you're talking about formatting, you could use something like:

```
string formatted = value.ToString("0000");
```

... that will ensure there are at least 4 digits. (A format string of "D4" will have the same effect.) But you need to be very clear in your mind that this is *only* relevant in the string representation... it's not part of the *integer* value represented by `value`. Similarly, `value` has no notion of whether it's in decimal or hex - again, that's a property of how you format it.

(It's really important to understand this in reasonably simple cases like this, as it tends to make a lot *more* difference for things like date/time values, which again don't store any formatting information, and people often get confused.)

Note that there's one type which *may* surprise you: `decimal`. While it doesn't consider *leading* zeroes, it does have a notion of *trailing* zeroes (implicitly in the way it's stored), so 1.0m and 1.00m *are* distinguishable values.

Comment: thanx buddy for the detailed answer. Your answer also solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Integer wont accept leading zeros, it will only hold the real value of the integer.
The best we to have leading zeros is to convert it to string.

If you need a 4 digit value always, use the `.ToString` formatting to add leading `0's`.

```
int value = 23;
var result = value.ToString("0000");
```

or if you want to have a leading 00 to any number, better append 00 to the string equivalent of the integer.

```
int value = 23;
var result = "00" + value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming issue. Numbers have no leading zeroes.

There are two things here that you can do:

- If it is a number, then format it on the way out.
- If it is something like a code (article number etc.) - those are NOT NUMBERS.

The second point is important. Things like social security numbers, part numbers etc. are strings - with only numeric characters allowed. You never add or subtract them and you must be prepared for format changes. They are not integers or any other number form to start with.