# Is there a way I can left pad a number in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
phrasesPage.Title = "Timer: " + AS.timerSeconds.ToString();
```

The number of seconds can be anything from 120 to 0.  Is there a way that I can have that display as "Timer: " plus the numbers 120 ... 099 .. 002 ... 001 ... 000 .  In other words I need the number to show as three digits with left padding of 0's

Comment: This is the same answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros

Comment: Please do a search before posting a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ToString("000")` ought to work.

```
phrasesPage.Title = "Timer: " + AS.timerSeconds.ToString("000");
```

See [Custom Numeric Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) for other examples of things you can do with the format string.

Answer (score 1):

```
phrasesPage.Title = string.Format("Timer: {0:D3}", AS.timerSeconds);
```