# Padleft not adding zeros in strings when the length is under the length of the padleft?

Tags: c#, padleft

So I wanted to make a random timestamp generator in c# which had to be a string.

I came up with a random generator made out of loads of `random.next`'s
but when the day month hour or minute is under 10 it has to have a zero in front, or the string `length` won't reach the length I need it to be which is like this:

`1111/11/11 11:11`

without spaces and slashes so it'll be like this:

`111111111111`

but if the minute is like 9 then it'll be like this

`11111111119`

which is not long enough!

**here is my code now**

```
decimal cijfer;
string tijd;
string jaar;
string maand;
string dag;
string uur;
string minuten;

Random random = new Random();

cijfer = random.Next(64, 94);
jaar = random.Next(1943, 2020).ToString();
maand = random.Next(0, 13).ToString();
dag = random.Next(0, 29).ToString();
uur = random.Next(0, 23).ToString();
minuten = random.Next(0, 61).ToString();

maand.PadLeft(2, '0');
dag.PadLeft(2, '0');
uur.PadLeft(2, '0');
minuten.PadLeft(2, '0');

tijd = jaar + maand + dag + uur + minuten;

Console.WriteLine(tijd);
Console.ReadLine();
```

which does not work and I do not understand why.

Comment: `PadLeft` returns a new string. It does not mutate the string that's passed in. You need to assign the result of your padding.

Comment: @JonathonChase is correct. Also, that applies to **all** functions that interact with strings. A `string` is never altered (unless you do something dodgy like `unsafe`) since they are **immutable**. So if you ever call **any** function on a string it will almost certainly _seem to_ do nothing unless you do something with the **result** of the function call.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working) covers why code you have does not work (string modification functions returns new value), but what you really looking for is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros - `String.Format("{0:D4}{1:D2}...", random.Next(1943, 2020), random.Next(0, 13)…`

Answer (score 0):

[String.PadLeft Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> **Returns a new string** of a specified length in which the beginning of the current string is padded with spaces or with a specified
>   Unicode character.

You will need to modify to take the new string into account

```
maand = maand.PadLeft(2, '0');
dag = dag.PadLeft(2, '0');
uur = uur.PadLeft(2, '0');
minuten = minuten.PadLeft(2, '0');

tijd = jaar + maand + dag + uur + minuten;
```

Comment: already fixed it like this:

Comment: string maandd = maand.PadLeft(2, '0');
            string dagg = dag.PadLeft(2, '0');
            string uurr= uur.PadLeft(2, '0');
            string minutenn = minuten.PadLeft(2, '0');
            tijd = jaar + maandd + dagg + uurr + minutenn;

Comment: but thanks! :) also sorry for the multiple posts I thought I could just enter to the next sentence...